# Python scipy.special.mathieu equation

Tags: python-3.x, physics

I am trying to relate the Mathieu equation found in [Wikipedia Mathieu Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function/) to the one implemented in scipy.special. In Wikipedia there are 3 inputs, a,q and the parameter along which the integration proceeds.

mathieu_cem takes three inputs, an order (integer), a characteristic parameter and the the parameter along which the integration proceeds in degrees. I am trying to relate a and q to the order and characteristic parameter.

If it helps I am trying to simulate a quadrupole mass spectrometer with a and q being trapping parameters.

Comment: You may want to post this on the SciPy users mailing list. See https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html

Comment: With the help of some in the scipy users mailing lists I have found that "a" is the characteristic number and "q" is the characteristic parameter. For a given 'q', there is only a discrete set of values of 'a' for which the equation has even periodic solutions.  Call these a_0(q), a_1(q), a_2(q), etc.  'mathieu_a(m, q)' computes a_m(q), and 'mathieu_cem(m, q, x)' is the even periodic solution associated with a_m(q). Hope this helps someone at some point.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of some in the scipy users mailing lists I have found that "a" is the characteristic number and "q" is the characteristic parameter. For a given 'q', there is only a discrete set of values of 'a' for which the equation has even periodic solutions. Call these a_0(q), a_1(q), a_2(q), etc. 'mathieu_a(m, q)' computes a_m(q), and 'mathieu_cem(m, q, x)' is the even periodic solution associated with a_m(q). Hope this helps someone at some point.